# How to stop getting router login page while portforwarding in 777vr1 Airtel router to access Apache2 in local machine be through the Internet

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, router, apache-http-server

I installed Apache in Ubuntu Desktop for working with Moodle, I want the Moodle website in var/www/html to be accessible through the internet. With an experienced friend's guidance, I setup port forwarding in my Airtel 777vr1 wifi router.

Step 1: I logged in to my wifi router and setup the DHCP Static with my Ubuntu Desktop's Mac Address [DHCP Static setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqiLD.png)

Step 2: Under NAT section, I setup the DMZ: [NAT DMZ Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuYHL.png)

Step 3: Under the NAT section, I setup the virtual server as :[NAT Virtual Server setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATjiz.png)

Step 4: I reboot the router, went to google and got my public IP by searching for "my ip",

When I go to my public IP in the browser while using my wifi network, instead of getting the default Apache 2 success page, I get redirected to my router login:
https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/login.htm

When I try from my mobile using mobile internet, the page is not at all loading.

Where am I wrong? How do I access my webpage running in Ubuntu Desktop's Apache2 through the internet?

EDIT: Should I configure the WAN section under the Setup menu?

Comment: Maybe there's an setting for disabling WAN admin access?

Comment: Also I think you should keep only the first NAT rule and remove the other one and all the DMZ ones.

Comment: Hey thanks, I couldn't find the WAN admin access, and removing NAT rule also didnt work